# Need Help: Apex batch Class

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I'm still trying to figure out how batch work.  `My error is SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY [9]|Database.getQueryLocator(String)`.

This is what I have so far.  I'm trying to upsert a list of records using apex batch.  Your help is appreciated.

`Combine__c` is the external ID field.

My Batch Class:

```
global class batchUpsertRecords implements Database.Batchable<sObject> { 
    global final String query; 

    global batchUpsertRecords(Business__c[] busRec) {
       Business__c[] query = busRec;
    } 

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query); 
    } 

    global void execute( Database.BatchableContext BC, Business__c[] scope){

        database.Upsert(Scope,business__c.Combine__c,false);
        Upsert scope; 

    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email 
                            FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :BC.getJobId()]     
    }
```

My Schedulable Class:

```
global class SFParAccelIntegration1 implements Schedulable{

    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx)
    {
        SFParAccelIntegration1.combineIdBusiness();

    }


    public Static Void combineIdBusiness(){
        //Match CombineID to Account records and populate fields in Business object Salesforce section
        List<Business__c> businesses = new List<Business__c>();
        Set<string> combineIds = new Set<string>();

        for(Business__c bus : [Select Combine__c from Business__c limit 50000]) {
            combineIds.add(bus.Combine__c);
        }

        Business__c[] busRec = New Business__c[]{};

        //Get Account Data and Assign Values to Business
        For(Account a: [SELECT ID, Combine__c,Name,Total_Seat_Count__c,                 Number_of_FTE__c FROM Account WHERE Combine__c IN :combineIds]){
            busRec.add(New Business__c(Combine__c = a.Combine__c, 
             acctId__c = a.ID, SF_Total_Seat_Count__c = a.Total_Seat_Count__c,
             SF_Number_of_FTE__c = a.Number_of_FTE__c));

        }

        //system.debug(busRec);
        System.debug('combineIdBusiness1 Records Count - ' + busRec.size());

        //String query = 'SELECT Id,CreatedDate FROM Merchandise__c '; 
        batchUpsertRecords c = new batchUpsertRecords(busRec); 
        Database.executeBatch(c); 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that your're not storing the array passed in to the constructor into the member variable you're using in the start method:

```
// member variable is a String which is not what you want
global final String query; 

global batchUpsertRecords(Business__c[] busRec) {

    // this creates a new local variable called query which exists on the stack
    // and is removed when this constructor finishes
    Business__c[] query = busRec;
} 

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    // this is referencing the String member variable, which is still null
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query); 
}
```

You'll need to run the query to select records inside of the `Start` method, so what you can do is change your code so that you pass in a set of Ids, and use that in the query:

```
// doesn't need to be visible outside of the batch class
private Set<Id> records;

global batchUpsertRecords(Set<Id> records) {
   this.records = records;
} 

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return Database.getQueryLocator([select Id, Etc__c from Object__c
                                     where Id in : records]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @LaceySnr, I get a compile error at the line "return Database.getQueryLocator(query); " .  The error is "Argument must be an inline query"

Comment: Ah, I'd not actually looked at using that constructor this way before so didn't realise. Will update now.

Comment: Thanks Lacey, I resolved it by moving my query into my batch class and not passing it in.  A little restructuring was required on my codes.  I appreciate your help on this.